# How many Threads in my method?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm been searching the web for this answer and cannot find anything that really makes since to me.

I have a program that I am running and I want to count how many threads are in my method at a given time.

I have code in my Main() function:

```
Parallel.Invoke(MyMethod,MyMethod,MyMethod,MyMethod);


private static void MyMethod()
{
    //how many threads are waiting here???  <--- this is what I am after
    lock (myObj)
    {
        //one thread at a time please
    }
}
```

Can anyone shed light here??

Comment: Just to be clear, do you want to look this information up in another thread running in your program, or just look and see while you are debugging and you need to find out where to find it in Visual Studio?

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to track such informations and depending on them. If you need something like this in production code then most likely you have something wrong with design.

Comment: @Zuljin It could be useful to log to help find just what is wrong with a design.

Answer (score 12):

There is no way to directly query how many threads are in a given function.  The only way is to do manual tracking

```
private static int s_threadCount;

private static void MyMethod() {
  Interlocked.Increment(ref s_threadCount);
  try {
    ...
  } finally {
    Interlocked.Decrement(ref s_threadCount);
  }
}
```

Note: If this method can be recursively entered this won't accurately count the number of threads but instead will count number of threads + number of times they recursively entered the function.

Comment: That would explain why I can't find it :)   Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

The only way to do that would be to add a counter:

```
static int counter;
... 
static void SomeMethod() {
    int threadsInMethod = Interlocked.Increment(ref counter);
    try {
        code here
    } finally {
        Interlocked.Decrement(ref counter);
    }
}
```

Caveat: if the method is re-entrant it will overcount itself while nested.

Answer (score 1):

Not expecting many simultaneous enter/leaves and don't care about re-entrancy:

```
static int _cThreads;
static void SomeMethod()
{
  Interlocked.Increment(ref _cThreads);
  try
  {
    /* blah */
  }
  finally
  {
    Interlocked.Decrement(ref _cThreads);
  }
}
```

Do care about re-entrancy:

```
static IDictionary<int, int> _cThreads; // ConcurrentDictionary or alternative thread-safe dictionary
static void SomeMethod()
{
  if(_cThreads.ContainsKey(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId))//note that only this thread will hit this key
    _cThreads[Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId]++
  else
    _cThreads[Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId] = 1;
  try
  {
    /* blah */
   //When I care about the count then it's _cThreads.Values.Where(v => v != 0).Count()
   //which will mutate while we're trying to count it, but then any
   //answer to this is going to have a degree of staleness
   /*blah*/
  }
  finally
  {
    _cThreads[Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId]--;
  }
}
```

If you don't care about re-entrancy, but are expecting lots of simultaneous, but won't want to check the total every time, then use a striped counter. This will be appreciably slower with low contention, but much faster with high contention between cores, and may be applicable to your case.